# Why female academy bathrooms so visible from outside?

Tags: plot-explanation, police-academy

In *Police Academy (1984)*, Cadet Mahoney is able to enjoy the view of the female shower room.

[image]

Why are the female academy bathrooms so visible from outside?

Comment: Because it's *funny*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Police Academy is a series of parody and satire comedies set at a Police Academy. It would be highly unlikely that a real police Academy would place a shower room in that location without appropriate blocking of the windows. They would get sued quickly.

This is just a joke or visual gag.